# Is there a way to check when two NFC enabled Android devices go out of range?

Tags: android, nfc, nfc-p2p, android-beam

After I transfered data between two Android devices using Android Beam, I am looking for a way to be notified when these devices go out of range.

Answer (score 0):

No, Android does not provide an API for this.

If peer-to-peer mode/Android Beam is not a requirement, if both devices have Android 4.4+, and if your app runs in the foreground on at least one of the devices, then you could use a combination of HCE on one device and reader mode on the other device. Then, on the reader side, you could continuously send commands to the HCE side. If communication fails, you would know that the devices are no longer in range of each other.